# I don't know where to start with WSDL and SOAP in PHP 5.2+

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm a web services newbie and I've tried to learn it looking for tutorials in google... but I didn't found anything really helpfull...

Do you know any tutorial / web page / documentation for web services using PHP 5 native SOAP client? I need to implement a SOAP client for fetch/send data from a IIS server (for hotels reservations).

Is there some server that I can make tests with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://mssoapinterop.org/asmx/WSDL/WSDLInteropTestRpcEncService.wsdl');
$result = $client->echoString('hello');
print_r($result);
?>
```